# Masking divide by 0 exception assembly masm

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32, fpu

```
TITLE Unmasking an Exception    (Exceptions.asm)

; This program shows how to mask (set) and unmask (clear) the divide by zero
; exception flag.

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
ctrlWord WORD ?
val1 DWORD 1
val2 REAL8 0.0

.code
main PROC
finit       ; initialize FPU (divide by zero is masked)

; By unmasking, we enable the divide by zero exception.

fstcw   ctrlWord                ; get the control word
and ctrlWord,1111111111111011b  ; unmask Divide by 0
fldcw   ctrlWord                ; load it back into FPU

fild    val1
fdiv    val2                        ; divide by zero
fst val2

exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Hi everyone, i am very new to masm and am taking myself through some online projects i can find and am having trouble with this one, as you can see it unmasks the divide by 0 exception but how can i edit this to mask that same exception? If you can please explain and be as detailed as possible that will help out a ton!

Comment: Set the same bit to 1 instead of clearing it to 0? Use bitwise `OR`.

Comment: See, im very very noob at this so i dont understand what you mean by that. )=

Comment: Learn how [bitwise operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) work, that's elementary to any programming. Then use `or ctrlWord,100b`.

Comment: Ok i will read up on that and your saying that replacing the and ctrlWord,1111111111111011b with or ctrlWord,100b?

Comment: Yes. That `and` is clearing bit #2 (since you used it you should know what it does...). So the counterpart is setting that bit to 1.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help! Im going to read that link you posted and hopefully be able to figure this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> fstcw   ctrlWord                ; get the control word
> and ctrlWord,1111111111111011b  ; unmask Divide by 0
> fldcw   ctrlWord                ; load it back into FPU
> ```

The mask bit (ZM) for the zero-divide exception is bit 2 of the FPU control word. It would improve readability if you didn't write a long masking value like "1111111111111011b".
Since bit 2 is represented by the value 4, a more readable way to clear this bit is:

```
and ctrlWord, not(4)
```

Some people will even prefer to write `and ctrlWord, not(1<<2)` since this one still retains reference to the bit number (2 in this case).

Now when adopting this improvement, masking the zero-divide exception becomes a matter of changing the `and` into an `or` and dropping the *not* operator.

```
and ctrlWord, not(4)    ---->    or ctrlWord, 4
```

---

As an alternative you can also clear or set a bit using `btr` and `bts` instructions:

```
and ctrlWord, not(4)    ---->    btr ctrlWord, 2          ;Clears bit 2
or  ctrlWord, 4         ---->    bts ctrlWord, 2          ;Sets bit 2
```